# command mysql starts mariaDB instead of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

This is probably really dumb question... I followed a tutorial on mysql and php and after this code (namely just `mysql`) I should be greeted with Welcome to mySQL message. I am a little confused about why MariaDB is starting instead. Can you help me out what I need to change?

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4
Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Comment: [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) is the open source and free version of MySQL

Comment: aaah I was right. It really is dumb :D thank you

Comment: @JayBlanchard: That's not strictly true... MySQL itself is open source and free; MariaDB (maintained by the original MySQL developers) is a fork of MySQL (now maintained by Oracle) that aims for improved performance and features whilst maintaining binary compatibility.

Comment: Point taken @eggyal.  It is such an interesting set of circumstances.